# The requested URL /pls/apex/wwv_flow.accept was not found

Tags: oracle-apex

I'm running into a very similar error. I have a table with 104 columns. I have a form that has 100 items exactly on it (BTW, do buttons count as part of the item count?). When I click either the APPLY_CHANGES button or the DELETE button, I get the error:

The requested URL /pls/apex/wwv_flow.accept was not found ....

Answer (score 1):

The error is probably because you are missing a branch (after processing) to the page you want.

And if you are using Apex 4.2 the item limit has been raise from 100 to *200 enterable items per page* as you can read in [here](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/HTMDB/limits002.htm#HTMDB28632)
I don't believe buttons count for that limit since they refer *enterable items*.